# Consul API, Retrieve services instances list from all nodes

Tags: consul

I've explored service catalog, all I can see are the actual Service names, but not each service instance.
for e.g using Consul API/CLI,
I can only see Service-A,
But I prefer to see all instances under it.

- Service-A-abc
- Service-A-xyz
- Service-A-123

How can I get the all services instances from all nodes together?

Answer (score 1):

You can't get this information directly.

The only way to get an entire list is to write a script that first enumerates the services by name (/v1/catalog/services) and then enumerates the instance by service name (/v1/catalog/service/<service_name>).

Rinse and repeat.